# Eloquent stores Array-casted value in other order

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my code I have an Eloquent model which has one JSON-column `steps`, which is casted as array:

```
protected $casts = [
    'steps'  => 'array',
];
```

But if I know update the column with an array like this:

```
    $model->update([
        'steps' => [
            'connect' => 'A', 'clone' => 'A'
        ]
    ]);
```

Anything internally changes the order of json-array which is stored to the database, which looks like this now:

[image]

Any ideas how to prevent Eloquent from changing the order of the array items while storing them?

Little Update: The array is always sorted alphabetically by the keys before stored.

Comment: Mysql will sort it alphabetically before storing. Why do you want it in the same order as you send? Stored order shouldn't pose any problems in json columns, no? if you really need to store in the same order, you could perhaps store json encoded string in a plain old text type column.

Comment: Ah okay, so not Eloquent is ordering, MySQL itself... I need to store it in "my" order as these are different steps of a process with a state (running, finished, etc.). Hm, I could parse/serialize myself yes, but the casting works very well excepting this ordering. Maybe there is another solution to prevent mysql from re-order them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure should be like this:

```
[
    {"connect": "A"},
    {"clone": "A"}
]
```

because this is steps array and any step should be considered as a separate entity.

```
$model->update([
    'steps' => [
        ['connect' => 'A'],
        ['clone' => 'A']
    ]
]);
```

In this way not only you have right structure to store in DB but also you can store it in the order you want.

Comment: It required several changes in the code to handle the new structure but that solved the problem for me. Thank you :-)